# In Django I'm trying templates folder but it is not going in templates folder

Tags: django, templates

I am facing the following error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/check.html

Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    webapp/
    [name='index']
    check [name='check']
    admin/

The current path, check.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Please follow the tutorial. Templates don't have anything to do with URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You have `webapp/`, `check`  and `admin/` url patterns, you should do the following to make `check/` work:

1. You write a view :

```py
def check(request):
       return render(request, 'check.html')
```

2. You create a url pattern (You apparently did):

```py
from .views import check
urlpatterns = [
     path('check/', check, name = "check"),
]
```

*Remember to add the slash (/) after `check`*

Now you can visit **http:localhost:8000/check/** and that should work

Comment: its not working but from different site i got a solution . thank you for your efforts.

Comment: {% url 'app_name:file_name' %}